# Establish LTE-internet connectivity

Tags: connectivity

I am trying to establish internet connectivity using a SIM card.

Running the command `nmcli radio` shows WWAN to be enabled, however the command:

```
nmcli device status
```

returns:

```
DEVICE TYPE STATE CONNECTION
cdc-wdm0 gsm unmanaged ---
```

According to `nmcli -m 0` I have LTE reception with 71% signal quality:

[image]

Here is some more information about the system:

```
uname -r
4.15.0-112-generic
```

[image]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: honestly, I could not think of another way to include all this essential information in the post

Comment: Copy and paste as text?

Comment: since there is no internet connectivity, this is a difficult task